# Подсчет с группировкой в MySQL

Tags: запрос, база-данных, mysql

Есть табличка с полями типа int ( ID (AI) и IDUSER )

Как одним запросом (или с вложенными) подсчитать количество уникальных ID (или строк), в которых количество уникальных IDUSER не больше 2 и среди них есть определенный (подается на вход функции скрипта).

Например есть записи:

```
ID -- IDUSER
 1 -- 31
 1 -- 42
 1 -- 53
 2 -- 31
 2 -- 55
 3 -- 31
 3 -- 66
```

В результате выборки по IDUSER=31 должно вернуть 2, а например, по IDUSER=55 вернуть должно 1.

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: почему 31 3 раза повторяется,но должно вернуть 2 ?

Comment: потому что один раз IDUSER=31 встречается в ID=1, а у ID=1 уникальных IDUSER больше 2, потому его не считаем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct count(ID) from table where ((select count(*) from table where IDUSER = 'XXX') < 3);
```

Comment: не, не работает. в табличке сейчас записи (попарно id - iduser)

1-3
1-4
2-3
2-4
3-4
3-3
222-555
222-556

выдает 0, если в запросе изменить 3, допустим на 5, то выдаст 4

и в запросе видимо ошибка, не **select distinct count(ID)**, а **select count(distinct ID)**

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(ID) AS 'cnt',IDUSER FROM table
WHERE IDUSER=31 GROUP BY IDUSER HAVING cnt>2
```

Comment: тоже что-то не то, при таблице что в комментарие ответа Gorets выдавало правильно, а я взял и добавил еще строку в таблицу

    1-3
    1-4
    2-3
    2-4
    2-555
    3-4
    3-3
    222-555
    222-556

Теперь при IDUSER=3 должно выдавать 2, а выдает 3 :(